# Hadoop Quering after mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Hello i recently started reading about Hadoop .
and i have a few questions, hope you could help me.

Lets say i have run Map Reduce Java job on multiple-node Cluster .
And i have one file has been spited into 10 around the different Data Nodes.

Now Lets Say i have Written a query for the main file-

1. Does Execution plan received from main Name Node ?
2. Does it knows where all the partial files are located ?
3. Will it get all data from all the partial files ?
4. Can i have more than one partial file on same data node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Does Execution plan received from main Name Node ? ***No, task is scheduled by taskrunner, namenode contains meta data about your data. i.e. where the split part of your file is kept.*** 
2. Does it knows where all the partial files are located ? ***yes, refer point 1***

3. Will it get all data from all the partial files ? ***no, your program will be sent to the nodes, data never comes to program.***

4. Can i have more than one partial file on same data node ? ***yes, depending upon the availability and space constraint, it is possible however it is also necessary the at least one replication of your data is not present in same node. so that if this node goes down we still have access to the data.***